# Confusion about a practical example of FIFO Page Replacement Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, memory, memory-management, fifo

I'm doing some theoretical examples with different page replacement algorithms, in order to get a better understanding for when I actually write the code. I'm kind of confused about this example.

> Given below is a physical memory with 4 tiles (4 sections?). The following pages are visited one after the other:
>
> `R = 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4`
>
> Run  the FIFO page replacement algorithm on R with 4 tiles.

I know that  when a page needs to be swapped in, the operating system swaps out the page which has been in the memory for the longest period of time. In practice I'll have:

```
Time    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
Page    1 2 3 2 4 5 3 6 1 4  2  3  1  4
Tile 1  1 1 1 1 1 5 5
Tile 2    2 2 2 2 2 2
Tile 3      3 3 3 3 3
Tile 4          4 4 4
```

I'm not sure what happens at time = 8. I know that it won't replace page 5 and 4, but I'm not sure between 3 and 2. Since at time = 4 we have a 2, does it mean that page 3 will be replaced? Or is it that, since at time = 4, we already had 2 in the memory, therefore at time = 8 we replace 2?

Comment: Don't know why you think t=4 is a special time.  In a FIFO cache, tiles are filled (evicting any previous page) in round-robin fashion.  Tile 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2 etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIFO (First In, First out) means here: If space is needed for a new entry, the oldest entry will be replaced. This is in contrast to LRU (Last recently Used), wherever the entry that has not been used for the longest time is replaced. Consider your memory with four tiles at time 5:

```
Tile  Page   Time of loading
1     1      1
2     2      2
3     3      3
4     4      5
```

At time 6, space for page 5 is needed, so you had to replace one of the pages in the memory. According to the FIFO principle, page 1 is replaced here:

```
Tile  Page   Time of loading
1     5      6
2     2      2
3     3      3
4     4      5
```

This event repeats itself at the time 8, the oldest page in memory will be replaced:

```
Tile  Page   Time of loading
1     5      6
2     6      8
3     3      3
4     4      5
```

So it is helpful here to write the time of creation while doing this assignment.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up! I was just confused about what happens when you have to replace a page that's in the memory "twice" - as in at first it was added and we had a page fault but then we had a page hit because the page was already present in memory.